# Why I can't throw an exception in the process method of my applet?

Tags: javacard

Below you see a program that throw an exception in reception of any command after SELECT APDU command :

```
public class MyApp extends Applet  {


    private MyApp() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new MyApp().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()){
            return;
        }
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0002);

    }

}
```

The question is: Why transmission of any APDU commands (except that SELECT APDU command) fail?

```
OSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090002 -s 0000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0

Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 02
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)

Sending: 00 00 00 00
APDU transmit failed: Transmit failed
```

Is it restricted to use exceptions in the body of process method?

Comment: Well, arguing from the code it should work. Please try to throw an exception inside the `selectingApplet()` method to verify you actually selected that Applet.

Comment: @PaulBastian I replaced `0x0000` with a short number greater than `0x6100` (or equal with it) and now, the transmission doesn't failed anymore.

Comment: ok thats good. I would be interested what card nehaved like this?

Comment: @PaulBastian Based on the ATR (`3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 12 00 90 00`) it is a  _Brazilian "e-CPF"_ card. Can we have a short conversation in SO chatroom plz?

Comment: @PaulBastian I create a room here  : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74027/jcop-cards-api-and-gemalto-developer-suite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but likely your problem is with the status word used. You should keep to ISO 7816-4 defined status words. Try a few in the 6xxx ranges. You may have a different response for T=0 and T=1.

Comment: I replaced `0x0002` with numbers greater than or equal with `0x6100`, and the communication succeeded now. There is another problem, I receive `0x9000` always(Instead of the SW that I put in the `ISOException` method). I will ask it as a new question.

Comment: For the new problem : I tried another tool instead of OpenSC, and now I receive the same SW that I want instead of `0x9000`. So I guess, this new problem is related to the OpenSC tool, not my card or my program.

Comment: Excuse me dear Maarten, Why this issuer implement a mechanism to check if the SW is compatible with 7816-4? I tried the first program in another card, and it works fine. i.e the new card returns `0x0002` successfully. Why my previous card doesn't support those SWs? Does it have any advantages?

Comment: It could be the difference between T=0 and T=1. For T=0 the transport protocol application protocol are linked to each other (byte oriented). This is not true for T=1. Of course it's hard to go any further than this, I don't know why one implementer would go one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The exception status word must conform to the 7816 specification.Such as ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);

Maybe your program needs to write:

public void process(APDU apdu)
    {

```
    if (selectingApplet())
    {
        return;
    }

    byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
    switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])
    {
    case (byte)0x00:
        //......
        break;
    default:
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
}
```